# Cordova - CSS Snap Scroll does not work on the device

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to perform a **snap scroll** in a hybrid application with **Apache Cordova** and **OnsenUI**. The problem is that the Snap Scroll works in the browser (responsive mode) but when I compile my app to my Android device, it doesn't work (I guess it won't work on iOS either)

```
.snap-container{
    overflow: hidden auto;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    -webkit-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.snap-content{
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: end; /* || start*/
    /*position: relative;    */
}
```